# Page refresh redirects to another page

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have integrated Facebook login for authentication in my application.

After user logs in, application redirects user to the logged in page but when user refreshes or clicks on another menu tab, application redirects it to the home page (logged out).

Here the sample controller code.

```
@RequestMapping("/user={userId}/dashboard")
public ModelAndView login(@PathVariable("userId") String Id, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
         {
    ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView();

    try {
        FBGraph fbGraph = new FBGraph(accessToken);
        String graph = fbGraph.getFBGraph();
        Map<String, String> fbProfileData = fbGraph.getGraphData(graph);
        modelandview.setViewName("UserCreateExam");
        modelandview.addObject("fbname", fbProfileData.get("name"));
        modelandview.addObject("email", fbProfileData.get("email"));
        modelandview.addObject("id", fbProfileData.get("id"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return modelandview;
}
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Can we see your spring security config?

Comment: (How) are you passing this login info from page to page and checking on each page that the user is logged in?

Comment: @RC. I am not using Spring Security. I have manually built login flow for Facebook.

Comment: @Emil I have initialized public variable for controller.

Comment: Then can you post relevant part of your implementation. (what is `accessToken`, `FBGraph`, etc) As is I don't see how anyone could help you, we have too little information.

Comment: @RC. accessToken is temporary unique token given by Facebook, which we can use to retrieve user's data from Facebook. FBGraph is a format/structure that Facebook uses to provide its data.